# Статическое объявление переменной внутри функции

Tags: c, static

Вопрос такой: почему первое объявление и определение статической переменной не влияет на последующие вызовы той же функции? Да,понятное дело, что значение статической переменной, объявленной внутри функции, сохраняется между своими вызовами.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function (int a, int b) {
   static int st = 0; //???
   st = st + a + b + 1;
   return st;
}

int main (void) { 
  int result = function(1,1);
  printf("%d\n",result);
  result = function(1,1);
  printf("%d\n",result);
  result = function(1,1);
  printf("%d\n",result);
  return 0;
}
```

Результат: 3, 6, 9
Скажите, как это делается на уровне компилятора? Почему игнорируется последующее определение переменной при втором и третьем вызове функции?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле любые  переменные создаются во время компиляции (а не при входе в функцию).

У статических будет фиксированный на все время исполнения программы адрес, а автоматические (такие как, например, `int result` внутри main в вашем примере) размещаются с *фиксированным смещением* от указателя стека. Т.е. компилятор генерит разный код для доступа к переменным разного класса (какой именно, зависит от архитектуры процессора) и их инициализации.

Присваивание значения (инициализация) статическим переменным вообще проводится *однократно* кодом, который выполняется *до вызова* main. Именно поэтому их текущее значение остается в памяти между вызовами функции.

Comment: Разве? (Это по первому параграфу) Компилятор лишь резервирует место для переменных на стеке, а во время запуска (особенно если код с реаллокацией — 99% вероятности) уже подставляются смещения и вычисляется адрес, если нужно.

Comment: @0andriy, и  все же, фактически переменные создает компилятор, генеря соответствующий код (в т.ч. меняющий указатель стека и т.п.). Для статиков он плюс к коду создает таблицу символов, которую потом использует линкер, ну а секции сделанные линкером пользует загрузчик, который читает сегменты text в память, настраивает (если требуется после линкера (системозависимо)) адресные константы, обнуляет bss, копирует по нужным адресам  константы, вызывает статические конструкторы а потом main. Но начальный импульс всей этой динамике дает компайлер. (по крайней мере мы в своем загрузчике делаем так)